# Angularjs best architecture

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm looking for best practices on services, controllers and directives for Angularjs 1.3.X.

**Here is the rules i noticed :**
 - The view (html) knows only the main controller and his scope
 - A directive should not have his own services

**So :**
 - The view (html) cannot call the services directly.
 - The view (html) must use the main controller to access the services.
 - The view must declare the binding between the directive and the main controller

**And then :**
In the code, if a directive have to call a business function F1 of services :
 - the main controller must publish a function F2 which wrap the function F1
 - the view must declare F2 in the directive configuration

You can look at the picture attached for a more visual explaination.

**Questions :**
 - Are you agree with those rules and the style of code ?
 - Do you have any additional rules ?
 - Why should we not follow these rules ?

[image]

Comment: How about directive -> service?

Comment: Small controller and a lot of service seems to be a good practice to me.

Comment: For me, Business Services must be access through the main controller.

Comment: Directive is basically component. I have no problem with calling service in directive. It can be independent on controller.

Comment: Your architecture will cause the root controller to be too complex on large applications, because it has to store all links to services used in application. I prefer split code into components. Each of components has its own controller and that controller calls some services where needed. This provides me clean logic separation.

Answer (score 1):

those are most popular styling guides and well discussed in my opinion (all three are collaborating):

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

https://github.com/jmcunningham/angularjs-styleguide

https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide

short answer: your approach seems very similar to those. you might want to take a closer look to them